# Wicket (9.8.0) application, deployed on Payara 5.201 throws exception when method of stateless beans is used

Tags: java, ejb, payara, wicketstuff

Using wicket version 9.8.0, I am trying to use WicketTester for application containing EJB injection related code.
I created application using 'wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html', and deployed it on Payara server '5.201'.
I added the JavaEEComponentInjector in WebApplication.
Deployment was successful, and I was able to see the page on web browser.
Complete code is available at https://github.com/rjngshn/WicketTesterEJB

After this I added one stateless bean as follows

```
package uk.ac.ox.ndph.ckb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * @date 2022-04-01
 * @author rajanis
 */
@Stateless
public class ControllerRts {
    private static int appId;
    private static String rtsPojo;
    public void init(String rtsServiceData){
        rtsPojo = rtsServiceData;
        appId = 2;
    } 

    public static int getAppId() {
        return appId;
    }
    
    public String getContactMail()  {
        return "ContactEmail";
    }

    public String getLoginMessage() {
        return "LoginMessage";
    }

}
```

And one singleton bean

```
package uk.ac.ox.ndph.ckb;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerConfig;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
/**
 * @date 2021-03-29
 * @author rajanis
 */
@Singleton
@Startup
public class RTInitializer {
    static int MIN_TO_MICRO_SEC = 60 * 1000;
    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;
    @EJB(name = "ControllerRts")
    private ControllerRts mControllerRts;

    // Default is 60 minutes
    private final int currentFrequency = 60;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        System.out.println("RTInitializer... starting timer with default config");
        if (!isEnvironmentSet()) {
            System.out.println("RTInitializer:In Init:Environment not set");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("RTInitializer .. Finished initializing");
        setTimer(currentFrequency);
    }

    /**
     * Specifying frequency of sending mails.
     * Method to initialize and
     *
     * @param dur
     */
    public void setTimer(int dur) {
        System.out.println("RTInitializer: Setting a programmatic timeout for download sweep frequency to " + dur  + " minutes from now.");
        Timer timer = timerService.createIntervalTimer(dur * MIN_TO_MICRO_SEC, dur * MIN_TO_MICRO_SEC, 
                new TimerConfig("Created new interval for CDAScheduler", false));
    }

    /**
     * The actual timer method which calls the EJB function to pull email
     * requests and sends emails.
     *
     * @param timer
     */
    @Timeout
    public void sweepDownloadsAndEmail(Timer timer) {
    }
    
    private boolean isEnvironmentSet() {
        String rtsServiceData = "Some string to connnect to service";
        mControllerRts.init(rtsServiceData);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I referred to the stateless beans as follows in BasicPage

```
@EJB(name = "ControllerRts")
private ControllerRts mControllerRts;
```

And invoked its method in 'onInitialize'

```
    add(new Label("helpMessage", mControllerRts.getContactMail()));
```

Now the deployment as well tests failed.

Exception for deployment was as follows:

```
    org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public uk.ac.ox.ndph.ckb.UserPage2()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:90)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider$Provision.getPage(PageProvider.java:369)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:170)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:231)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:202)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:910)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:63)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:294)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:277)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:208)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type net/sf/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor not present
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(ClassWriter.java:1019)
    at org.objectweb.asm.SymbolTable.addMergedType(SymbolTable.java:1200)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1299)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1244)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.computeAllFrames(MethodWriter.java:1610)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1546)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.CodeEmitter.visitMaxs(CodeEmitter.java:847)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.CodeEmitter.end_method(CodeEmitter.java:138)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitGetCallback(Enhancer.java:959)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:644)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:305)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.cglib.CglibProxyFactory.createProxy(CglibProxyFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory.createProxy(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:160)
    at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEProxyFieldValueFactory.getCachedProxy(JavaEEProxyFieldValueFactory.java:149)
    at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEProxyFieldValueFactory.getFieldValue(JavaEEProxyFieldValueFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:111)
    at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEComponentInjector.inject(JavaEEComponentInjector.java:68)
    at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEComponentInjector.onInstantiation(JavaEEComponentInjector.java:74)
    at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:38)
    at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:34)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.notify(ListenerCollection.java:80)
    at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.onInstantiation(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:33)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.<init>(Component.java:691)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.<init>(MarkupContainer.java:180)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.<init>(Page.java:171)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.<init>(Page.java:135)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.<init>(WebPage.java:74)
    at uk.ac.ox.ndph.ckb.BasePage.<init>(BasePage.java:23)
    at uk.ac.ox.ndph.ckb.UserPage2.<init>(UserPage2.java:9)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor not found by org.objectweb.asm [23]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1597)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(ClassWriter.java:1017)
    ... 88 more
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Example provided by wicket [link](https://github.com/bitstorm/Wicket-tutorial-examples/tree/master/EjbInjectionExample) gave same error.
Adding Jakarta dependency version (9.1.0) worked.

However adding same dependency in my project didn't work. Accessing method of stateless beans threw NullPointerExcetion.

Changing bean's annotation from '@Stateless' to '@ApplicationScoped', and accessing 'public static' variable instead of method from 'WebPage' ensured successful deployment, altough it will not fulfill my requirement.

Tests however fail with 'ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.EJB'

Comment: Contd...
Adding following dependency ensures successful execution of test. 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Latest code is committed to git link mentioned in original question.

Has anyone tried testing pages accessing methods of stateless beans via WicketTester in wicket version 9.8.0, payara 5.201?